# Angular with systemjs and typescript outFile still includes all files separetely too

Tags: angular, typescript, systemjs

I'm trying to use the Typescript compiler and the outFile function to bundle my sources into a single file and load that as normal with systemjs.

When I run the `tsc` command I get a nice `bundle.js`, which includes my `main` code. When I load it in the browser (either apache or lite server) the `bundle.js` gets loaded first as intended and then systemjs kicks in and starts loading all the .js files separately -- main.js, app.component.js, etc etc. There's no errors -- it simply works, but it shouldn't need to load all the seperate .js files..

I've looked hard at a related post ([Load combined modular typescript file with SystemJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35477093/load-combined-modular-typescript-file-with-systemjs)) but can't seem to find what I'm doing wrong..

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <base href="/">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Solid Timesheet: Time-tracking made easy!</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

  <script type="text/javascript">
    // temporary hack for enable bootstrap 4
    window.__theme = 'bs4';
  </script>
  <script>

    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
              (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    var localhost = document.location.href.match(/^http:\/\/localhost/);
    ga('create', 'UA-18982324-19', localhost ? 'none' : 'auto');
  </script>

  <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>

  <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.min.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>

  <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.min.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.min.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.min.js"></script>

  <script src="node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/bundles/ng2-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bundle.js"></script>

  <script>
    System.config({
      packages: {
        app: {
          format: 'register',
          defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        "ng2-bootstrap": {
          "defaultExtension": "js"
        },
      },
      map: {
        'ng2-bootstrap': 'node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/bundles/',
        moment: 'node_modules/moment/moment.js',
      }
    });
    System.import('app/main')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
  </script>
</head>

<!-- 3. Display the application -->
<body>
<div class="container">
  <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outFile": "bundle.js"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings"
  ]
}
```

I'm using typescript 1.8.9

Answer (score 1):

I ran into that problem as well. I was able to bundle my app into one file (e.g. one network request) using outDir (instead of outFile) in my tsconfig and [SystemJS-Builder](https://github.com/systemjs/builder) (see [full source](https://github.com/smmorneau/tour-of-heroes) and [live example](https://tour-of-heroes-typescript.herokuapp.com/)).

**system.config.js**

```js
var map = {
  'app':                                'dist/js',
  'rxjs':                               'lib/js/rxjs',
  'angular2-in-memory-web-api':         'lib/js/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
  '@angular':                           'lib/js/@angular'
};

var packages = {
  'app':                                { main: 'main', defaultExtension: 'js' },
  'rxjs':                               { defaultExtension: 'js' },
  'angular2-in-memory-web-api':         { defaultExtension: 'js' }
};

var packageNames = [
  '@angular/common',
  '@angular/compiler',
  '@angular/core',
  '@angular/http',
  '@angular/platform-browser',
  '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
  '@angular/router',
  '@angular/router-deprecated',
  '@angular/testing',
  '@angular/upgrade',
];

packageNames.forEach(function(pkgName) {
  packages[pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
});

System.config({
  map: map,
  packages: packages
});
```

**tsconfig.json**

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "public/dist/js",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "ES5"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "filesGlob": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "typings/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <base href="/">
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/styles.min.css"> <!--compiled global scss styles-->

    <script src="lib/js/vendors.min.js"></script> <!--bundled dependencies-->
    <script src="dist/js/app.min.js"></script> <!--bundled source-->
</head>
<body class="container">
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

**gulpfile.js**

A set of tasks which uses tsc to compile, and systemjs-builder to bundle your app.

```js
// Compile TypeScript to JS
gulp.task('compile:ts', function () {
  return gulp
    .src(tscConfig.filesGlob)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(tsc(tscConfig.compilerOptions))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/dist'));
});

// Generate systemjs-based builds
gulp.task('bundle:js', function() {
  var builder = new sysBuilder('public', './system.config.js');
  return builder.buildStatic('app', 'public/dist/js/app.min.js');
});

// Minify JS bundle
gulp.task('minify:js', function() {
  return gulp
    .src('public/dist/js/app.min.js')
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/dist/js'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you need to remove this block from your SystemJS configuration:

```
System.config({
  packages: {
    app: { // <-----------
      format: 'register',
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    },
    (...)
  }
});
```

When specifying a `outFile` property, the TypeScript compiler generates a file that explicitly registers modules by name like this:

```
System.register('app.component', [ ...
```

They aren't anonymous modules as before. This way you don't need to configure SystemJS to associate JS files with module names (what you do with the `packages` block).

See this question for more details:

- [How do I actually deploy an Angular 2 + Typescript + systemjs app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36285064/how-do-i-actually-deploy-an-angular-2-typescript-systemjs-app/36315060)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. Unfortunately I already tried removing both the app block and the whole System.config block and both give the same result: the page is stuck at "Loading...". the angular2-polyfills.min.js throws 
angular2-polyfills.min.js:1 Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <(…)
Which seems to be because app/main is loaded but not found and therefore returns the index.html source.

Comment: I had this problem. Perhaps you could move the `System.import` at the end of the `body` block of your page...